# Android how to set image to imageview from url

Tags: android

```
try
{
  URL newurl = new URL("here my image url");
  Bitmap  bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());

    img_View.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

I used above this code

But still I cannot load this image to `ImageView`, Nothing is getting loaded.

could help me ?

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Comment: Use libraries like Glide or Picasso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

1.you can user [Glide library](http://%202%20down%20vote%20accepted%20%09%20%20you%20can%20download%20image%20from%20url%20in%20two%20ways%20%201.you%20can%20user%20Glide%20library%20to%20load%20image%20from%20url%20look%20the%20below%20code%20it%20can%20help%20you%20in%20simple%20way%20%20compile%20this%20library%20%20compile%20'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'%20%20than%20load%20image%20like%20this%20%20Glide.with(HomeClass.this)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.load(url)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.centerCrop()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.skipMemoryCache(true)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.dontAnimate()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.into(imageview);%20%202%20.try%20this%20if%20you%20dont%20want%20to%20use%20third%20party%20library%20%20%20new%20DownloadImage(imamgeview).execute(url);%20%20create%20a%20Async%20Task%20%20public%20class%20DownloadImage%20extends%20AsyncTask%3CString,%20Void,%20Bitmap%3E%20%7B%20ImageView%20bmImage;%20%20public%20DownloadImage(ImageView%20bmImage)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20this.bmImage%20=%20(ImageView%20)%20bmImage;%20%7D%20%20protected%20Bitmap%20doInBackground(String...%20urls)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20String%20urldisplay%20=%20urls[0];%20%20%20%20%20Bitmap%20mIcon11%20=%20null;%20%20%20%20%20try%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20InputStream%20in%20=%20new%20java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mIcon11%20=%20BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20catch%20(Exception%20e)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Log.d(%22Error%22,%20e.getStackTrace().toString());%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20return%20mIcon11;%20%7D%20%20protected%20void%20onPostExecute(Bitmap%20result)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);%20%7D%20%7D%20%20i%20hope%20that%20it%20will%20work%20in%20your%20case) to load image from url look the below code it can help you in simple way

compile this library

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
```

than load image like this

```
Glide.with(HomeClass.this)
            .load(url)
            .centerCrop()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .dontAnimate()
            .into(imageview);
```

**2 .try this if you dont want to use third party library**

```
 new DownloadImage(imamgeview).execute(url);
```

**create a Async Task**

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = (ImageView ) bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
```

**i hope that it will work in your case**